# Unable to program a loop for regression analysis in R

Tags: r, loops, linear-regression, repeat

I have a problem with my R code. I would like to run about 100 regressions and perform this process with a loop. I have tried to program the loop myself using help from YouTube and the like, but I am getting nowhere. Therefore, I would like to ask you if you can help me.
Specifically, it's about the following:
I have a dataset of the 100 companies in the Nasdaq100 and I would like to regress the sales per share with the stock price performance on a quarterly basis. Another problem is that the data set contains these 100 companies and a subset with the respective ticker symbol has to be created for each additional company so that R can access it correctly for each regression.

Here is an excerpt from the code:

```
Nasdaq_100 = read_xlsx("Nasdaq_100_Sales_Data.xlsx")

#Correlation between quarterly close price and Sales of AMD
AMD <- subset (Nasdaq_100, Nasdaq_100$TickerSymbol=="AMD")
AMD_regression = lm(AMD$Sales ~ AMD$Stockprice_quarterly, data = Nasdaq_100)
summary(AMD_regression)
```

Can you help me to program this loop for regression analysis?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert this to a for loop, first get a list of the .xlsx files in your working directory:

```
require(data.table)
myfiles <- list.files(pattern="*.xlsx")
```

Then loop through each file, and saving with minor modifications to your existing code:

```
for (file in myfiles) {
Nasdaq_100 <- data.table::fread(file)
AMD <- subset (Nasdaq_100, Nasdaq_100$TickerSymbol=="AMD")
AMD_regression = lm(AMD$Sales ~ AMD$Stockprice_quarterly, data = Nasdaq_100)
summary(AMD_regression)
data.table::fwrite(AMD_regression, file=paste0("output_", file), quote = F, sep = "\t", row.names = F)
}
```

Copy-paste in r and Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
file <- choose.files()

lmset <- data.frame(x='x',y='y')

for(i in seq_len(100))

{

  data <- read_excel(file,sheet=i)

  lmset <- rbind(lmset,lm(AMD$Sales~AMD$Stockprice_quarterly,data=data)$coefficients)

}
```

Comment: You should explain the code you post as answers. [Code only answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256359/flag-try-this-code-answers-as-very-low-quality) are many times flagged for review like this one was.